# access vba like operator return only first result

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a textbox to input search word. I use this code to search:

```
Dim strfilter As String
Strfilter = "[VendorName] like '*" & Me.searchtxt.value & "*'"
Me.Filter = strfilter
Me.FilterOn= true
```

But only the first result is shown, while there are several records for that word.
Can you help me, please?

---

Update:

Search term:      tec

Sample table:

```
     VendorName        No of product

     Techno Fol            4
     Niktec                6
     Dkm                   1
     Samatech              5
     HighBond              2
```

There are 3 records that their "vendorName" fields contain the term "tec", but the VBA code return only "Techno Fol".

Comment: The `like` operator does not need asterisks.

Comment: @Paul Ogilvie I want to search within the words

Comment: All the same: like searches for things that look "like" your search criterium.

Comment: your code works as written so it is likely a setting problem.  My first guess is that the forms default view property is set to datasheet or single form.  You should have a record selector at the bottom of the form in form view.  if my guess is right then the record selector will show the correct number of records and you can cycle through them there.  You can also switch the default view to continuous records.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie, LIKE does need wildcard. LIKE without wildcard might as well be equal sign.